# Child controls not visible when usercontrol background set transparent

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm creating a user control in Windows Form application which looks like below :

[image]

I want to make the only backColor/background of user control to be transparent and not the controls on it. For example here maroon color T-shape should be as it is but background (i.e gray color ) should be transparent.

I tried below code in constructor of user control but it does not work.

```
this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor, true);
this.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
```

I have gone through many links but none of them works.

Below is the code of usercontrol. I have used 2 LineShape control to draw the T-shape and change it as when control resizes. I need to use this control in Windows form but with transparent background.

```
public partial class UserControl1: UserControl
{
    public UserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor, true);
        this.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
    }

    private void UserControl1_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.lineShape1.StartPoint = new Point((int)(this.Width / 2), 2);
        this.lineShape1.EndPoint = new Point((int)(this.Width / 2), this.Height - 2);
        this.lineShape1.Update();

        this.lineShape2.StartPoint = new Point(1, 1);
        this.lineShape2.EndPoint = new Point(this.Width - 1, 1);
        this.lineShape2.Update();
        this.Refresh();
    }
}
```

I need to use this control in windows form where winform is of different backcolor and hence backcolor/background of usercontrol must be transparent.

Comment: Please show us the XAML code.

Comment: do u want complete code ? i'm using this usercontrol on winforms

Comment: At least a snippet so I can understand the structure of your UserControl. edit: I see you use Winforms.. Sorry my fault.

Comment: Johannes Wanzek - updated the code

Comment: What does "does not work" mean in your case? Also, have you checked the child controls' properties? Maybe they inherit the transparency from the parent and you might need to actively make them opaque.

Comment: Don't use the LineShape control, it prevents transparency from working.  Simply implement the Paint event and draw the shape with the Graphics class.  Set the user control's ResizeRedraw property to true to get it to automatically repaint when the control is resized.

Comment: @Hans - ok let me tryout your idea.

Comment: @Hans it did not work :(